# How to detect end-of-file when using open/read?

Tags: c, linux

I am using open/read functions, there's feof for fopen/fread to detect end-of-file, what's the equivalent way for open/read?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [man read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), ...

Comment: It's not clear though if either eof nullifies the number of bytes read before reaching it, or if it is suggested to consider eof only after the next read() when there are zero bytes left.

Comment: I guess the man page does not spell it out, but to me it would make no sense to read a bunch of bytes but return a different length, so presumably the 2nd to last call to read would read data up to the end of the file, returning the number of bytes read as usual, and then the next (and final) call to read would return 0 as there is nothing left to read.